# Trailing zero on decimal

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a string which looks like this `512.3` is there a way to add a trailing zero so it looks like this `512.30`

Just to clarify (sorry I didn't know there where different ways etc.)

My string is an amount which is passed so changes all the time I only need the trailing zero on amounts like `512.3`, `512.4`,`512.5` etc. as some of my amounts will pass values like `512.33` and `512.44` and so on

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: Can you give us some more context?  What is the situation which needs the extra 0?  There are like 10 ways to do this and any of them will be appropriate in different situations.

Comment: @NickLarsen or do it the way I noted below everytime and then you never have to worry about culture variations.

Comment: @drachenstern I'm not worried about culture variations... he said he has a `string`! and everyone keeps answering it like he has a either a float, double or decimal!  Seems like a simple string concatenation problem to me, but I figured I would have the OP clarify before I even attempt to answer or whip out up votes for answers that make tons of assumptions.  Thats not the kind of questions that are going to help the community.

Comment: @NickLarsen you make a good point. And if he always wants to add a zero no matter what then a concat `+ "0"` would probably be faster coding and maintenance than a `.ToString(formatString)` anyways. Let's see if he responds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
float.Parse("512.3").ToString("0.00");
```

It would give the number with two decimal digits.

Comment: Sorry, saw just now you're using VB.NET - should be the same syntax.

Comment: You'll want to leave the semicolon off the end, as they are working in VB.NET and not C# :)

Comment: the .ToString would also work fine on any object (generally speaking). Also generally safe is the `String.Format(formatString,object)` method.

Comment: @Delebrin - yep see my comment.. not sure about VB syntax so prefer not to mess around and end up with code invalid in both :|

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: I was thinking since it's already a string, just do something like `myNumber = myNumber + "0"`.  He really hasn't given enough information to answer this question, as easy as it seems.

Comment: @ShadowWizard in the future, note that if you'll visit the MSDN for a specific function in the .NET library (like `.ToString()`) it will list the VB and C# and other managed library versions of the code.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Thanks that works - just to clarify the VB.Net syntax for this is `Single.Parse(Amount).ToString("0.00")`

Comment: @JamieTaylor ~ To use less code and to have it work for any object, see my example. Glad you got what you needed.

Comment: @drachenstern - thanks, always good to learn something new.. :) @Jamie - you can use this instead, it will save some CPU cycles plus looking better: String.Format("{0:F2}", Amount)

Answer (score 4):

You're going to want to use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) or some derivation thereof, and the [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) will look like

```
myString = String.Format("{0:F2}",myObject);
```

Also note that format strings can be used in the `.ToString("F2")` method (notice I included the format string `F2` inside there already.

See the MSDN links above for a more thorough and definitive explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If it's VB.NET it seems like the simplest solution would be:

```
FormatNumber("512.3", 2)
```

Which would return 512.30

Answer (score 0):

Format(5.12, "0.00") this will format it as two decimals.

Comment: But this isn't culture invariant.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use String.Format

```
decimal your_number = 1452.66m;
string str = String.Format("{0:C}", your_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Single.Parse("512.3").ToString("0.00") ' VB Version